# msp430 schematic serial data and serial clock

Tags: i2c, msp430

I highlighted below, something that was connected to the serial clock and serial data. I am not quite sure what this connections means and what exactly its doing. it seems to me that there is another sla and sda connecting to the main microcontroller. if anyone could please explain i would appreciate it very much.

[image: partial schematic]

Comment: (1) The [CAT24FC32](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=CAT24C32) is an EEPROM, that's connected through the I2C.  (2) I see only one SDA and SCL.  I don't see another SDA and SCL which you are writing about.  (3) I don't understand the purpose of R23.  If it were my I2C bus, I wouldn't want any resistance there.

Comment: If you can't take 20 seconds of your precious time to rotate a picture, I'm not going to give you 20 seconds to read the rest of your question.

Comment: Agreed @pipe - I've rotated the original (partial) schematic, since I was answering the question anyway. The OP really should take care of such details, of course (please take note, *studious student* :-) ).

Comment: @pipe åh, förlåt jag visste inte att bilden var orienterad felaktigt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite broad, and you haven't given detail of any previous research, so I'll just give some basic answers:

> I highlighted below, something that was connected to the serial clock and serial data.

As kindly mentioned by *Nick Alexeev*, the [CAT24FC32](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=CAT24C32) you have highlighted is an I²C EEPROM. As a student (judging by your username) you need to (quickly!) learn how to find, read, and assimilate information from datasheets.

> I am not quite sure what this connections means and what exactly its doing.

**Read the datasheets**.

Look at the datasheets for the relevant devices i.e. that I²C EEPROM and the [TUSB3410](http://www.ti.com/product/TUSB3410) (which is a UART-to-USB bridge). Then you will see that the [TUSB3410 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tusb3410) explains it can load its firmware from an attached I²C EEPROM.

> it seems to me that there is another sla and sda [...]

Please take care with the details. The signal names are not "sla and sda" - they are SCL and SDA, as stated in the I²C specification.

> [...] connecting to the main microcontroller

You didn't explain where that schematic came from. I recognise it as being *part* of the schematic from the emulator section of an [MSP430G2 Launchpad](http://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430G2) board (perhaps also used by TI in other places too).

When you ask a question, you need to give context and background for what you are asking, and explain why you want that information - otherwise any answers might not be suitable for whatever *you* really want, and no-one wants to spend time writing an answer to then be told "that didn't help".

Based on the full schematic in the [MSP430G2 Launchpad User Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau318g/slau318g.pdf), the SCL and SDA signals on the edge of the partial schematic you gave, go to the MSP430F16x MCU which is the emulator/programmer chip built-into that Launchpad board.

You must be careful using vague terms like "the main microcontroller". Many people would not call that MSP430F16x chip, the *main* microcontroller. Instead they would think you are referring to the MCU which contains the user program on the Launchpad. Again, please take care with the details. Be *specific*.

The reason why that MSP430F16x MCU is also connected to the I²C bus (and therefore connected to that I²C EEPROM) is so this MCU can write to the I²C EEPROM, to change / fix / upgrade the TUSB3410 code which it contains.

Comment: alright, thanks for being so kind as to answer my question. i have never taken an embeddeds course so i wouldn't know what broad is in this regard. I will try next to be as specific as i can.

Comment: @studiousstudent - You're welcome :-) If this has answered your question, please consider [accepting it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), to mark the question as "answered". Your question appears broad (or unclear) because you ask about "this connections" which are just an I2C bus, and didn't list your research. Therefore you might have been wanting info about I2C; or about that EEPROM; or about how that EEPROM is used by the TUSB3410; but then you ask about the I2C signals going to somewhere that you *didn't* highlight. Each of those are separate questions :-) HTH.